# Apex managed sharing for customer community plus users

Tags: customer-community, apex-managed-sharing

We need to enable apex managed sharing for our customer community plus users. Are there any workarounds (or) out of the box solutions to enable this option.

From the SalesForce release notes it appears only role based sharing is available for customer community plus users.

http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_networks_ccp_license.htm

What are the available options to enable the managed sharing option?

Comment: If you want managed sharing you need Partner Communities. There is no way to add managed sharing to a Community Plus licence.

Comment: @CaspNZ - I donot think apex managed sharing has been enabled for partner communities. Can you refer to me to the right documentation. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do anything special to "enable" Apex managed sharing for Customer Community Plus users. You just need to make sure the code that manipulates `Share` records runs in [system context](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm), which is the default behavior for triggers. Alternatively you can put your method inside a `without sharing` class. See the last section in the "Sharing a Record Using Apex" page in the [*Force.com Apex Code Developer's Guide*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm).